# Oracle: creating a query that gives a score to a record (using IF ELSE in a query)

Tags: sql, oracle

Should I use something like SUM(IF... sintax)?

Comment: http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html

Answer (score 6):

`IF` is a PL/SQL construct.  It is not available in SQL.

Depending on the problem you are trying to solve, you could do something like this with a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT col1,
       SUM( CASE WHEN col2 = 'A'
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END) num_with_col2_of_A
  FROM some_table
 GROUP BY col1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use PL/SQL: If you just need something like an `IF ... ELSE` construct you could use [DECODE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php)

```
SELECT DECODE(col1, 'first value', 1, 'second value' 2, 0) FROM dual
```

where *'first value'* would be your `IF` and *'second value'* would be your `ELSE` and *0* your default score.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use if else in sql query ..

better use `case .. when` statement .. it would solve your problem ..

[click here for more detail](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/case_when.html)